# How do I update elements of array using onChange with hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I believe this should be something simple but I find it difficult to implement, and all the answers I've seen so far doesn't really tackle this specific problem.
I have a state like this.

```
const [formFields, setFormFields ] = useState({
formTitle: '',
field: [
    {name: '', options: ['optionA', 'optionB', 'OptionC'] },
]})
```

I want to update the elements of the `options` array using onChangeText/onChange.

My code

```
field.options.map((option) => (
<TextInput value={option} 
onChangeText={(e) => e}
/>))
```

Please how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

```js
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState({
  formTitle: "",
  field: [{ name: "", options: ["optionA", "optionB", "OptionC"] }],
});

const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  setFormFields({
    ...formFields,
    field: formFields.field.map((field) => ({ ...filed, options: /*your change */ })),
  });
};
```

Or use library like [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/#with-immer). And then you just modify specific filed.

```js
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  setFormFields(
    produce(formFields, (draft) => {
      draft.field[0].options = /*your change */;

      // Or all the fields
      draft.field.forEach((field) => {
        field.options = /*your change */;
      });
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem is that, how do I detect which element from the options array has changed and update it appropriately? I know I'm supposed to use the index of that element to do that but I can think of how to achieve it. For example, the elements from the options array are all rendered in a TextInput. I want to be able to use onChange to change 'optionB'  to 'something' by editing the TextInput that rendered 'optionB'. Please how can I do this?

Comment: I don't know what exactly your TextInput componend does. But if you want to know index of option inside event handler than you can embrace closure. 
`field.options.map((option, i) => (
<TextInput value={option} 
onChangeText={(i) => getEventHandler(i)}
/>))`
and then modify functions from my answer to `const getEventHandler = i => e => // rest is the same`

Comment: In case the values of your fields are not dynamic or depend on dynamic values from the database, you can try Formik - https://formik.org/.

It abstracts the complexity of updating and validating form fields.